# Custom Sort li items from CMS using jQuery

Tags: jquery, sorting, content-management-system

I am using a CMS called Perch and I need to sort this dynamically loaded list into a different order.  I cannot do it fro the CMS side, I was hoping to find a way to do it on the Front-End using jQuery.  It is possible?  Here is the way the code is put out by the CMS.

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="archive-r.php?tag=appetizers" rel="tag">Appetizers (4)</a></li>
    <li><a href="archive-r.php?tag=beverages" rel="tag">Beverages (2)</a></li>
    <li><a href="archive-r.php?tag=breakfast" rel="tag">Breakfast (2)</a></li>
    <li><a href="archive-r.php?tag=desserts" rel="tag">Desserts (4)</a></li>
    <li><a href="archive-r.php?tag=entrees" rel="tag">Entrees (14)</a></li>
    <li><a href="archive-r.php?tag=salads" rel="tag">Salads (14)</a></li>
    <li><a href="archive-r.php?tag=side-dishes" rel="tag">Side Dishes (8)</a></li>
    <li><a href="archive-r.php?tag=soups" rel="tag">Soups (1)</a></li>
</ul>
```

Right now it is in alphabetical order.  I need it to reflect the following order. 
 
Appetizers
Soups
Salads
Entrees
Side Dishes
Beverages
Desserts

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See http://jsfiddle.net/29CGB/3/ for an example.  You need an index to sort on, in this case you have defined a custom sort.  Since the a tag's href is unique, I'm using that to define the sort. Here's the code, note I didn't add all  of the items to the array:

```
var sortOrder = ['appetizers', 'soups', 'salads', 'entrees', 'side-dishes']; //make sure to finish this
var newList = $('ul li').sort(function (li1, li2) {
    return sortOrder.indexOf($(li1).find('a').attr('href').replace('archive-r.php?tag=', '')) > sortOrder.indexOf($(li2).find('a').attr('href').replace('archive-r.php?tag=', '')) ?  1 : -1;
});
$('ul').html(newList);
```